# Access to referenced elements in QList and QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlist, qsharedpointer

There is a QList member variable named `m_noteList` containing QSharedPointer elements of class `Note`.

```
private: 
   QList< QSharedPointer<Note> > m_noteList;
```

If a new note is created, its reference is appended to the list:

```
void Traymenu::newNote(){
    QSharedPointer<Note> note(new Note(this));
    m_noteList << note;
}
```

For each Note-element, whichs pointers are in m_noteList, I want to get its title and add it to my contextmenu. Purpose is to click on that title to open the note:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < m_noteList.count() ; i++ ) {
    std::string menuEntryName = m_noteList[i].getTitle();
    QAction *openNote = m_mainContextMenu.addAction(menuEntryName);
}
```

I get an error

```
C:\project\traymenu.cpp:43: Fehler: 'class QSharedPointer<Note>' has no member named 'getTitle'
     std::string menuEntryName = &m_noteList[i].getTitle();
                                                ^
```

Basically I want to get access to the objects that are referenced in the `m_noteList`. How do I do that? I thought with `m_noteList[i]` to get access to that element, but obviously the compiler expects something of type `QSharedPointer`. Why?

Comment: The error says that a `QSharedPointer` does not have the method `getTitle`. That's true. You should dereference your pointer to access members of the `Note` class : `m_noteList[i].data()->getTitle();`

Comment: Ah, so this is they way it works. Thank you, will you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSharedPointer` basically wraps your pointer. So you can't access directly with the '.' operator, this is the reason why you get this error : `getTitle` is not part of the class `QSharedPointer`.

However you have multiple ways to retrieve the actual pointer :

1. `data` : not the simplest way but it's explicit, and it sometimes matters
2. `operator->` : so you can use your `QSharedPointer` like an actual pointer `m_noteList[i]->getTitle();`
3. `operator*` : to do something like `(*m_noteList[i]).getTitle();`